# Cannot open a port on Debian

Tags: debian, iptables, firewalld

I'm have a Debian installation

```
~$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/
```

where I installed PostgreSQL

```
 PostgreSQL 11.3 (Debian 11.3-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

PostgreSQL is running, but I can use it from another machine: I opened the 5432 por via firewalld

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
8443/tcp 5432/tcp
```

but it does not work.

This locally

```
~$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

this is from my machine (on another vlan)

```
:> telnet 192.168.13.183 5432
Trying 192.168.13.183...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

this is from another machine (in same vlan as the debian)

```
telnet 192.168.13.183 5432
Trying 192.168.13.183...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.13.183: Connection refused
```

So I turn off the firewalld (just for test) but I get the same results.
After that I tried to do the same but with iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

With same results
What I am missing here?

just check this (thanks [@thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/151151/thomas)):

```
netstat -tulpan | grep postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6386/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      6386/postgres       
udp6       0      0 ::1:44652               ::1:44652               ESTABLISHED 6386/postgres

lsof -n -i:5432
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 6386 postgres    3u  IPv6  72390      0t0  TCP [::1]:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 6386 postgres    5u  IPv4  72391      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:postgresql (LISTEN
```

Comment: Is your service even listening on something else than `localhost`? Check that with `lsof -n -i:5432` and/or `netstat -tulpan | grep postgres`.

Comment: @Thomas just listen to localhost.... add the coment on the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`postgresql` by default only listens on localhost (*127.0.0.1* and *::1*). To change this behavior you have to configure other listening addresses manually in `postgresql.conf`, normally located in `$PGDATA`.

To make postgres e.g. to listen also on the local address 10.0.10.156, you would have to specify the `listen_addresses` as follows.

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost, 10.0.10.156'
```

To make postgres listen on all interfaces, you also can use a wildcard.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

After this change, postgres needs to be restarted. I also would recommend to check if the result meets your expectations.

---

Output of `lsof` with a postgres listening on localhost and 10.0.10.156.

```
# lsof -n -i:5432
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 7893 postgres    3u  IPv6  55868      0t0  TCP [::1]:postgres (LISTEN)
postgres 7893 postgres    4u  IPv4  55869      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:postgres (LISTEN)
postgres 7893 postgres    5u  IPv4  55870      0t0  TCP 10.0.10.156:postgres (LISTEN)
```

---

Output of `lsof` with a postgres listening on all interfaces.

```
# lsof -n -i:5432
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 7527 postgres    3u  IPv4  54903      0t0  TCP *:postgres (LISTEN)
postgres 7527 postgres    4u  IPv6  54904      0t0  TCP *:postgres (LISTEN)
```